# send several messages in one connection, python socketIO

Tags: python, socket.io

I'm using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client

```
ping = SocketIO(host, port)
ping.define(SIO)
ping.message(PING)
ping.wait(seconds=1)
```

namespace definition skipped.
this code works ok - I send one message and receive one from server.
But can't figure out how to send few messages in one connection and analyze responses in middle - I need to make short interactive session.

Answer (score 0):

may be will be useful for someone someday...
i've figured out:

```
ping = SocketIO(host, port)
ping.define(SIO)
ping.message(PING)
ping.wait(seconds=1)
callResponceAnalyzer()
ping.message(MESSAGE1)
ping.wait(seconds=1)
```